# C - Passing an array between functions gets different values

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So I'm trying to write a function that'll search a word in a 2D bulk.
The function returns an (int) array of size [3] with values as the answer.
Here is my main() function:

```
void main() {
    char bulk[L][L];
    for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
        for (int j = 0;j < L;j++)
            scanf_s(" %c", &bulk[i][j]);
    }
    int *arr = search(&bulk, L, "bc");
    printf("ARR: %d, %d, %d\n", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
}
```

And here's the search() function:

```
int *search(char(*bulk)[L], int size, char *word) {
    int arr[3] = { 0,0,0 };
    int flag = 9;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (bulk[i][j] == *word) {
                if (checkRight(bulk, i, j, word)) flag=0;
            }
            if (flag != 9) {
                arr[0] = i;
                arr[1] = j;
                arr[2] = flag;
                printf("ARR: %d, %d, %d\n", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
                return arr;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

The checkRight() function works well, it returns 0/1 for if the word exists to the right. The problem is that the two **printf**'s are printing different values.

Output for search(): **"ARR: 0,1,0".**

Output for main(): **"ARR: -858993460, -858993460, 0".**

I assume it's pointer-related but I'm struggling with finding the problem. Any ideas?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: `return arr` - you are returning the address of a temporary that expired as soon as the `search` function returned. Dereferencing that address invokes *undefined behavior*. Pass `arr` as an in/out additional parameter, or stuff it inside a `struct`, which can be returned by-value. Even a `static int arr[3];` may be appropriate. Resist the temptation for anything dynamic for this.

Comment: THANK YOU! static int arr[3] worked for me, I guess I missed the fact that it's temporary..

Comment: The function call to `scanf_s` is missing an argument. Did you read the [man page for `scanf_s`?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) *"Unlike `scanf` and `wscanf`, `scanf_s` and `wscanf_s` require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable."* Please enable and fix all compiler warnings. Better is to reject Microsoft's non-standard "safer" functions.

Comment: Though returning a pointer to a static array is at least semantically correct, it is a style that has fallen from grace because it is not thread safe.  Even though you don't need to worry about multiple threads in your particular case, it's a good idea to learn early how to avoid such problems, and to practice doing so.  One alternative would be for the *caller* to be responsible for declaring the array -- it can then pass a pointer to it into the function, and let the function fill it in.

Comment: @WeatherVane I completely concur with most of that, but the `_s` functions are no longer microsoft specific. They're part of [Annex K (normative) Bounds-checking interfaces](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for that info. The community usually considers MS extensions to be dong, whereas GNU extensions are ding. Does GCC have these extensions?

Comment: Your compiler should warn your. Don't ignore them! `&bulk` is not `char (*)[L]`.

Comment: @WeatherVane no clue. I tend to agree with the community on that assessment, at least on the MS perspective. Personally I steer clear from *any* extensions, as I don't like having to explain to some PM that spams email, crafts PowerPoint decks, and attends meetings for a living why switching toolchain vendors is a pain. MS makes it hard enough as it is.

Comment: @WhozCraig love the Frish Yeats shuffle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return arr;
```

In here you are returning the address of the first value in the array, this address points to a temporary value inside the stack frame of the function search.

try to pass arr as a parameter or using "static int arr[3]" in order to make the array not temporary.